# How does Whatsapp use my mobile fingerprint in their app?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, permissions, fingerprint

How does **Whatsapp** access my fingerprint?

WhatsApp did not ask permission to use my fingerprint.

Then how do they use my fingerprint for unlocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated to 2.20.64 to check

WhatsApp does need fingerprint permission, under " `Use Fingerprint Hardware`" and `Use Biometric Hardware`"

You can check under permissions in Play Store - see "others"

Edit : If you are wondering why the app *doesn't ask* you explicitly for permission, the reason is simple - both the permissions quoted above are *normal* permissions for which user [approval is not required](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission). Also see [Permissions Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous)

> If an app declares in its manifest that it needs a *normal* permission, the system *automatically grants the app that permission at install time*. The system doesn't prompt the user to grant normal permissions, and *users cannot revoke these permissions*

(Emphasis supplied)

See this [Stack overflow Question - Android nougat USE_FINGERPRINT permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47428491/android-nougat-use-fingerprint-permissions#47429264), which states the same

Answer (score 0):

Any app including whatsapp cannot read/access your fingerprint data.

```
Your fingerprint data isn't shared with Google or any apps on your device. 
Apps are notified only whether your fingerprint was verified.
```

source - https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/6300638

Android OS might be doing the moderation here. An App might access/store this data only when you register your fingerprint with the app directly.